# How to get response from action dispatched in phpunit

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am dispatching some `POST` data to an action of a controller. That action echoes some json-encoded string. I want to verify that the json-encoded string of that action is as I want it. I want to know how I can get that string?

My test looks like this:

```
$this->request->setMethod('POST')
     ->setPost(['test' => 'databaseschema_Database']);

$params = ['action' => 'analysis', 'controller' => 'Index', 'module' => 'default'];
$urlParams = $this->urlizeOptions($params);
$url       = $this->url($urlParams);
$result    = $this->dispatch($url);

$this->assertJsonStringEqualsJsonString(
    $result, json_encode(["status" => "Success"])
);
```

My test is failing and I am getting following message:

```
1) IndexControllerTest::testAnalysisAction
Expected value JSON decode error - Unknown error
stdClass Object (...) does not match expected type "NULL".
```

Can any one guide me on how to do this?

Comment: dispatch() doesn't ever return anything, so you're comparing null to the json success string, which is why you're getting the error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do unit testing, what you really want to do is extract the json encoding into it's own class (or a method inside a utils class or something) and then test those method instead of your whole controller.

The problem with your approach is that when running phpunit, there is not $_POST array. The code above does not show what is happening, but I guess there is different behaviour when run through apache and cli which causes your test to fail.

I would create a TransformerClass and test this in isolation:

```
class JsonTransformer
{
    public function transformPostData(array $postArray)
    {
        // transformation happening
    }
}

class JsonTransformerTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testTransformPostData()
    {
        $transformer = new JsonTransformer();
        $data = array('action' => 'analysis', 'controller' => 'Index', 'module' => 'default');
        $result = $transformer->transformPostData(data);

        $this->assertJsonStringEqualsJsonString($result, json_encode(array("status" => "Success")));
    }
}
```

If you need to test your whole request/response, you would use some kind of HTTPClient, request the url, send the post data and see if the response is what you'd expect.

Everything in between (like faking the post data) leaves you with more problems and more code to maintain than it does you good.